# Как обезопасить продакшн на сервере с Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, безопасность, unix

Привет. В свете последних событий с моим продакшн-сервером, на который обрушилась брутфорс-атака на SSH, я настроил Fail2Ban и всерьёз задумался над безопасностью сервера в целом и у меня возник ряд вопросов, на который я бы хотел услышать ответы. Итак:

- Почему небезопасно работать под рутом?
- Как защитить SSH с помощью SSH-ключа и насколько это безопаснее простого логин-пароля?
- Что делать, если я потеряю свой SSH-ключ?

Comment: 1. Потому что можно случайно что-то сломать; 2. Это гуглится; 3. А что если вы забудете пароль?

Comment: @andreymal ну пароль-то я помню, он состоит у меня из 18 символов и установлен во многих местах и он хорошо залёг у меня в памяти, а ключ запомнить нереально - он состоит из множества букв разного регистра и цифр и сгенерирован случайным образом. Его невозможно запомнить. Его нужно где-то хранить, а это небезопасно.

Comment: «установлен во многих местах» автоматически делает пароль небезопасным

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin брутфорс сегодня обыденная практика. На только что созданном сервере уже лежат логи, что кто-то ломится. Дело в том, что боты сканируют подсети и проверяют возможные векторы атаки. Меняешь стандартный порт и уже норм)

Comment: Хорошо сгенерированный пароль вряд ли кто-то сможет подобрать. Брутфорсы проходятся по словарям. Поэтому тут дело в сложности и длине пароля.

Comment: Ха-ха, вот вы, автор, только что сделали свой пароль мене безопасным!

Comment: @tcpack4 я установил в качестве защиты SSH-порта Fail2Ban. А Nginx настроен таким образом, что доступ по IP-адресу блокируется и отдаётся код 444. С этим у меня всё в порядке. Меня больше волнует уровень безопасности, который даёт SSH-ключ и где его можно хранить без риска утери или угона.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin если у вашего домашнего компьютера есть риск утери или угона, то всё очень плохо. Алсо, простые пароли при потере SSH-ключа никто не отменяет и сам SSH-ключ тоже надо защищать столь же сложным паролем

Comment: @andreymal я могу хранить SSH-ключ на Яндекс.Диске, где доступ есть только если я просканирую QR-код смартфоном, но на компьютере Яндекс.Диск доступен словно это жёсткий диск без какой-либо авторизации. Этого и боюсь.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin а вот не надо хранить SSH-ключ на Яндекс.Диске

Comment: на дропбокс рабочий аккаунт закиньте, если паранойя, то в архиве с паролем)

Comment: @tcpack4 и так тоже не надо

Comment: @tcpack4 я ни разу не параноик. Просто осторожничаю :)

Comment: @andreymal есть более лучшее решение для бекапа на всякий случай?)

Comment: @tcpack4 пароль длиной 18 символов :)

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin используйте менеджер паролей. LastPass, например.

Answer (score 3):

2й год работаю под рутом на 3000 серверах в 15 стран мира пока ничего не сломано. По соображениям безопасности ключи использовать запрещено.

Главное читать внимательно документацию. Ключи могут стать большой проблемой если у вас постоянная текучка кадров, постоянная смена не рабочих станций на новые. Бронировать публичный хостинг от брут атак задача динамическая.

1. Анализируйте логи;
2. Обновляйте пакеты безопасности, в дистрибутивах поддерживаются автоматические обновления;
3. Придерживайтесь минимализма устаноаленных програм,
4. Составте отчет, что установленно какие права доступа имеет и т.д.;
5. Ограничте зоны, исключив не целевые страны из белого списка;
6. Поставте двойную авторизацию (стандарт в наши дни) и ограничте хосты для доступа по ssh;
7. Добавте в белую зону ваш публичный айпи офиса и дома от куда будет проводится подлючение;

По факту:

> Почему небезопасно работать под рутом?

Работа под любым пользователем в *nix ОС чревата проблемамы, если не знаеш, что творишь. Нет "защиты от дурака" как в Win. Удалял кучу своих файлов когда начинал работу, пример убийцы:

```
~$ rm -rf ~/Downlods/ *
```

Пробел поле последнего слеш сотрет весь ваш домашний каталог вместо очистки Downloads...

> Как защитить SSH с помощью SSH-ключа и насколько это безопаснее простого логин-пароля?

Удобнее это факт. Безопаснее, не совсем. Пример: станция была украдена с RSA ключем ко всей вашей сети, что делать? Админ в командировке :)

> Что делать, если я потеряю свой SSH-ключ?

На своем тестовом сервере я прошу тех поддержку сменить пароль, отключить авторизацию только по ключу.

---

дополнение 26/07/17

О настройке и хранении ключей.

Хашируйте known_hosts

```
~$ ssh-scankey -H hostname >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

**Ссылки**

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Guidelines/OpenSSH
- https://www.linux.com/learn/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo
- https://askubuntu.com/q/262937
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html#sec-audit_system_architecture

Comment: Двойная авторизация в SSH? Это что-то интересное.

Comment: А что с ключами не так? При постоянной текучке они наоборот должны сильно помогать: отозвать ключ намного проще, нежели менять пароль и сообщать новый всем оставшимся сотрудникам.

Comment: «станция была украдена с RSA ключем» — от которого ноль толку, потому что RSA-ключ запаролен, а пароль хрен подберёшь — безопасность не нарушается.

Comment: @andreymal Мониторить ключи на станциях это нужен отдель6ый сотрудник. Если пришел новый персонал, как залить ключ на все станции? Без DevOps инструментов... Я не противник ключей, хочу лиш показать, что это не панацея, как все статьи трубят. Скептик я.

Comment: А если сотрудник ушёл, как менять пароль на всех станциях? :)

Comment: @andreymal Ушел,  и унес все пароли в голове, которые остались в его мышечной памяти за 6 лет работы... паролИ никто не поменял, от них мало толку, когда ты не в белой зоне доступа к сети. VPN + firewall zones, пожалуй надежней, чем полагатся на пароли или ключи, как вы думаете?

Comment: Ну если так, то может быть)